# gdalinfo does not work

Tags: python, syntax-error, latitude-longitude, gdal, geotiff

The gdalinfo does not work in my Python script
Can anyone tell me what the prblem is?
I imported all the packages from osgeo, all the other functions work except gdal

Comment: I think should you paste your snippet and the traceback that you are getting.

Comment: As Senthil comments, we need to see your code and the error/trademark that you have. GDAL/OGR does have dependencies - have these been built? off the top of my head, Proj.4 is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

gdalinfo is a utility that works outside of the Python environment. It is used via the command line.